# Uploading to Google Cloud Storage throws SunCertPathBuilderException randomly

Tags: java, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Over the past couple of days we have been seeing the following exception when uploading to Google Cloud Storage:

*javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

*Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target*

Yesterday this was causing about 10% of uploads to fail from US West coast servers.
Today we are seeing 90% of uploads fail from our US East coast servers.

Uploads are going to a US bucket (Multi-Regional).

We are running Java 11 and google-cloud-storage-1.46.0.jar. This has been working perfectly for months, this is a recent issue.

Is anyone else seeing this problem currently? Any idea how to fix it? To me it looks like a fault Google's end, but they have not reported it.

Thanks,

Mike.

Comment: We are no longer getting errors on servers on the east coast, but they continue at a lower rate on the west coast. (Europe and asia server unaffected). I am surprised no one else has seen this problem. We have had over 3,000 failed uploads in the past 48 hours.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer occurring from any location.

I do not understand the cause of the failures.

My best guess is that either:

- Some of Googles servers were returning a certificate that is not trusted by the certs in OpenJDK 11.
- An odd networking fault.